# Highcharts Heatmap Show x-axis on top and bottom both

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

Is it possible to show the x-axis and corresponding labels on top and bottom of the graph instead of only the bottom?

Comment: It should be possible to use array of xAxes and use opposite for moving your xAxis to the top. Here you can find an example how it can work with standard chart: http://jsfiddle.net/csts55kf/

Comment: This is brilliant, also when you want to use a stacked column chart, instead of fiddling with the formatter! This should be the "answer"!